# MVC 3 How should I design my repository/DAL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, domain-driven-design

With the following domain model:
World -> Franchise -> Office -> Agent

I understand that repositories should return aggrigate roots, which of these domain entities is the aggrigate root? or all (do I need a repository for each)?

I want to be able to get entities via their id passed by url.  Where do I put these GetById methods?

If I want to get a list of all agents within a franchise with a partial first name of "Jo", how do I build that into the system?  Should I:
Have a method in the Franchise entity that's basically a .SelectMany linq statement?
or have a repository for Agent that has GetByPartialFirstName() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the domain logic, if the entity is to be consumed by its own then it is an aggregate root, if you want to get an instance of "Agent" and call methods directly from your consumer code then it should have it's own repository, otherwise if it is to be consumed as a part of "Office" and its methods are called from its root "Office" then it is not an aggregate root and you dont need to fetch it independently from repository.

Apply this rule to all the Entities to decide which to create a repository for.

Comment: Okay, it just seems like almost every entity will end up having a repository class and I'm worried this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I dont think it is an anti-pattern why would it be so ? if your use case is to fetch and save each entity then you need a repository for each .. that simple

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with repositories, but I would suggest that if you plan on having multiple ways to search for your agents, I would recommend creating a criteria interface/class.  This would allow you to do multiple types of combination searches with a single method call (firstname/lastname, firstname/city, etc).

(I like using interfaces to keep my application and datasource decoupled)

```
public IEnumerable/IQueryable<IAgent> Get(IAgentCriteria Criteria)
{
  if (Critiria == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

  var result = entities.Agents;

  if (!string.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace(Criteria.FirstNameStartsWith))
  {
    result = result.Where(x => x.FistName.StartsWith(Criteria.FirstNameStartsWith));
  }

  // etc etc
}
```